# Need help understanding this proof (computer science)

Tags: computer-science, proof

[image]

I don't understand how it's valid to present this counterexample. It doesn't satisfy () = (())
since () is not (()). () = ω(()) if f(n) is 2n and g(n) is n.

So how is it valid to simply "Let () = 2 and () = ." ?

Comment: Perhaps post this on math.stackexchange.com. As written, it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

But f(n) = 2n IS O(g(n)) for g(n) = n. Let n0 = 1 and c = 3. Then:

```
f(n) = 2n <= 3n = 3 * n = c * n = c * g(n), for n >= n0
```

Therefore, the counterexample is valid.